# jQuery .wrap(), anchors and IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, anchor

I am trying to wrap an anchor-tag around a block of code using jQuery (v1.2.6) by doing the follwing:

```
var link = $('<a>').attr('href','http://www.foo.bar');
$('#block').wrap(link);
```

This works perfectly fine in all browsers but (you guessed it) the Internet Explorer (all versions I can use to test it). I do know from other cases that the IE is hella picky when you insert code via JavaScript, but in this case I just don't know what could be wrong with this simple anchor element? Anyone got an idea? Btw: I already tried generating the anchor via `$('<a></a>')` as suggested on several other posts unfortunately, makes no difference for me.

Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using such an old version of jQuery, and have you tried (just to see if it would work) using a newer one (newest is 1.6.1 at the moment, I believe)?

Comment: I'm using a plugin to animate the clip-CSS-property that will only work on older versions of jquery, but maybe it's a good idea to try using a newer version once and see if this resolves the particular problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also, is `#block` a `div`? Technically, you can't put `<div>` inside `<a>` in HTML4, so that might be why IE is choking? (Workaround: use a `<span>` and give it `display: block` with CSS) In any case, it would also help if you provide a clearer explanation of your expected and actual result in IE. Does the DOM tree not end up correct? Can you not click the link? Both/neither?

Comment: #block is (despite the name) a span with an image inside :) but changing the jQuery-version (just up to 1.3.2 so my plugin will still work) did the trick. Btw: What happened in IE is that it just didn't insert the anchor into the DOM tree - which IE likes to do when it thinks that code is not valid (I had this before but not with something as simple as an anchor). Thanks for helping!

Comment: @m90: I'm not a veteran here myself, but I believe the thing to do in that case is add the answer yourself, and accept it, so the question shows up as being answered and closed. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried doing this, but I wasn't allowed to due to some time restriction, but now I am! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my jQuery to 1.3+ did the trick.

Apparently `var a = $('<a>');` in jQuery 1.2.6 and earlier will create a chunk of code that IE considers invalid and therefore will refuse to insert it into the DOM tree.