# Small jQuery script not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I wrote a small script for an eCommerce site that errors an order if certain conditions aren't met. Now I'm trying to write something so the continue button returns the user to their cart. I can't change the button to add a class.

The problem is that this script doesn't work in IE. I'm not overly familiar with the differences in how browsers handle JavaScript. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery("#shipping-method-buttons-container .button").wrap(function() {
               var link = jQuery('<a/>');
                link.attr('href', 'http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/');
               return link;
            });
        </script>
```

Update: I have since tested this in IE9 and IE10. I'm getting this problem in all IE browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340374/jquery-wrap-anchors-and-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 $("#shipping-method-buttons-container .button").click(function(){
     window.location = "http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working in IE and others

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#shipping-method-buttons-container .button").wrap(function() {
        var link = jQuery('<a></a>').attr('href', 'http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/');
        return link;
    });
});
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/S2YJX/3/)

Comment: This worked in other browsers for me outside of Magento (the software I'm using) but not inside. For some reason it still worked in Chrome but not IE in my application.

Comment: Ok, glad you got over the problem.